# Html Markup Abstraction and Consistency in SPAs

Tags: html, backbone.js, architecture, single-page-application, aura.js

I'm currently evaluating the use of [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/) along with [Aura.js](https://github.com/aurajs/aura) for building an enterprise scale SPA.

I have a nice Javascript architecture mapped out that provides abstraction, consistency, flexibility and no dependencies on any base libraries.

As I see it, in using any MV* pattern (and in particular Backbone), markup generation could be scattered throughout views via a combination of direct dom manipulation and external html templates.

I would like to apply the same principles to the html markup in my views as I have with my Javascript architecture.

1. **Abstraction** - Ideally I would like to provide developers with a simplified API for producing markup, potentially shielding them away from the css classes/markup structure being used.
2. **Consistency** - I would like to promote and control consistency in the markup produced within a team of developers.
3. **Flexibility** - I would like to avoid having to find and completely rewrite all instances of certain markup if there comes a need to change either the css classes/markup structure being used. Ideally I'd like any changes to be made in one place, that will propagate throughout all uses within the system.

As a practical example of how this can be achieved server-side, we currently use a suite of custom HtmlHelpers within ASP.NET MVC (similar in design to KendoUI). These helpers provide a nice fluent API for developers to use and centralise control of the markup that is generated.

However as we're moving towards client-side UI generation I'm not sure how to gain the same benefits that are available in server-side markup generation.

I appreciate templates can provide re-usable widgets throughout the UI, however that does not completely address the issues outlined above, which apply when creating those templates and the layout to contain them.

So to summarise my question...

**What practices can be employed to achieve control and consistency in markup generation within a team when developing enterprise scale SPAs?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your question is limited to Backbone.js and Aura, I'm not sure this qualifies as an answer, but I would definitely check 3 things

1. [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) and [AngularUI](http://angular-ui.github.com/) - the concept of directives, resembles the notion of [Web Components](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-components-intro-20120522/) (a work in progress W3C standard for web controls)
2. If you like typed coding, and likes to live on the bleeding edge, check [Dart Web UI](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/web-ui/) it also uses a pretty much similar concept
3. If you have to stay in Backbone land, then I would check [Backbone UI](http://perka.github.com/backbone-ui/) of course

I believe the first 2 have a better chance of answering your 3 requirements.

Comment: Thanks Eran. I'm still only evaluating the options so I'm not strictly tied to Backbone/Aura. I've looked into Dart but as you say it's too bleeding edge for us at the moment. AngularJS looks a viable alternative and I'm looking into it now so thanks for that. My only concern is that it seems there is no alternative but to jump into bed with something like AngularJS. Is trying to abstract the framework a really bad idea? I guess I'm just really concerned about future change.

Comment: I would bet on AngularJS only because it's strongly tries to stay around future standards (such as Web Components) and for me it somewhat resembles .NET components and JSP/JSF tag libraries (only much better). A great free resource on AngularJS is http://egghead.io/

One more thing worth considering, is dojo framework, it might not be the one with the most hype, but it's been here for a long time and it has a very nicely structured widget system.

If you are developing for inbound enterprise clients, Sencha (ExtJS) is also worth looking at, although it has mixed reviews in terms of performance

Comment: After researching AngularJS today I agree it seems like our best bet. I can see how the directives would provide the desired abstraction, consistency and flexibility that I'm looking for by providing a component based architecture. One final question, is it possible to override existing tags? e.g. Could I create a button directive for <button> tags to automatically provide the desired css for say a bootstrap button? I've seen the AngularUI Bootstrap project but that doesn't really abstract the css in the way that I'm looking to do.

Comment: @BrettPostin that is a very good question, don't know the answer though

Comment: No problem i'll ask on the Angular groups as it's quite specific. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Just for reference, it is possible to replace/manipulate existing tags. See example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/p5SXd/1/).